# Access text in Share Extension

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, ios-app-extension, ios8-share-extension

I am trying to create a share extension for my app. Instead of using the `SLComposeViewController` I am creating a custom view with `UIViewController`. However I am not sure how I should now access the text to display it in the label in my view?
What should I be doing?
Thank you